# How to segregate my data better within a Python class

Tags: python, class, subclass, inner-classes

I've been working on a project that is a calculator for an electronic part. This is my first full-scale Python project and it has gone through many iterations along the way.

The data is not organized as well as I would like, which I think is making it difficult to improve the program.

I have a class for the module, which has two parts inside of it. Each part has its own attributes that are independent of each other, and the whole module itself has some attributes that the parts don't care about, and some attributes that the parts need. The module also has to do some calculations based on the results of the independent calculations done inside the parts. [Here is a photo of the idea I'm trying to explain.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCZgM.png) *As an aside, sometimes there are modules with only one part, but I can suppress the other part by applying some 0's arrays. I would like to be able to have a module where the one part is entirely missing, but that is not my current goal.*

The problem is that my class has ~100 lines of self.XXX = None at the beginning to initialize everything, and several functions which IMO are repetitive. It is also quite difficult to traverse the data when stepping through the code - for example, I have to find variables like self.current__partA and self.current__partB. What I think would be helpful is to have something like self.partA.current. If it is done this way, I think it would be more readable.

The problem is, I tried subclasses and it seems like I can't achieve this kind of idea because when I initialize the subclass, I have to initalize a new superclass, meaning that there are two superclasses (two modules with a total of 4 parts, when I want 1 module/2 parts), so I can't really access the info of both subclasses from the superclass because each subclass will have its own instance of the superclass.

I also looked at inner classes but there is an issue where I don't think I can truly access the outer class from the inner class, which kind of defeats the purpose of using this. That could work to a degree, but it would make my code longer and less readable, from what I am seeing.

The first solutions I had were things like dictionaries, which I don't totally hate, but that lead to really janky code that had very little tolerance for errors. The reason is, when you add a list to a dictionary, you can't have a function that automatically throws an error. I can check the dictionary, but it just feels unnatural. It seems to me that it would make more sense to keep each value as a class variable and use functions, getters and setters to manipulate it through the calculation.

My main goal is to organize the data and code effectively so that I am using less lines of code and the program is easier to modify, and it is easier to step through the process. I am not entirely sold on the class structure, it just seemed to be the best way to accommodate what I am trying to do. Is there a way to achieve what I am asking here, or is there a generally more pythonic way to organize my code that would result in a more effective solution?

```
class Module:
def __init__(self, module_file):
    temp_ic, temp_value = self.get__corrected_value(module_file)
    temp_if, temp_vf = self.get__corrected_value(module_file)
    self.ic_value = interp1d(temp_ic, temp_value, fill_value='extrapolate')
    self.ic_esw_on = interp1d(self.get__corrected_esw(module_file), self.get__corrected_esw(module_file["ESWON - IC ESWON"]), fill_value='extrapolate')
    self.ic_esw_off = interp1d(self.get__corrected_esw(module_file["IC - IC ESWOFF"]), self.get__corrected_esw(module_file["ESWOFF - IC ESWOFF"]), fill_value='extrapolate')
    self.rg_on_esw_on = interp1d(module_file["RGON - ESWON RGON"], module_file["ESWON - ESWON RGON"], fill_value='extrapolate')
    self.rg_off_esw_off = interp1d(module_file["RGOFF - ESWOFF RGOFF"], module_file["ESWOFF - ESWOFF RGOFF"], fill_value='extrapolate')
    self.ic_err = interp1d(self.get__corrected_esw(module_file["IC - IC ERR"]), self.get__corrected_esw(module_file["ERR - IC ERR"]), fill_value='extrapolate')
    self.if_vf = interp1d(temp_if, temp_vf, fill_value='extrapolate')
    self.rg_on_err = interp1d(module_file["RGON - ERR RGON"], module_file["ERR - ERR RGON"], fill_value='extrapolate')
    self.nameplate_vcc = module_file['Nameplate VCC']
    if module_file['vcc_ratio'] > 0:
        self.vcc_ratio = module_file['vcc_ratio']
    else:
        self.vcc_ratio = 0
    self.name = self.get__module_name(module_file)
    self.current__PartA = []
    self.current__PartB = []
    self.some_thing_loss__PartA = []
    self.esw_on_loss = []
    self.esw_off_loss = []
    self.esw_loss__PartA = []
    self.energy__PartA = []
    self.value__PartA = []
    self.some_thing_loss__PartB = []
    self.err_loss = []
    self.energy__PartB = []
    self.value__PartB = []
    self.rg_scalar_esw_on = None
    self.rg_scalar_esw_off = None
    self.rg_scalar_err = None
    self.value_dc__PartA = module_file['PartA value DC']
    self.value_dc__PartB = module_file['PartB value DC']
    self.value_dc__module = module_file['Module value DC']
    self.trans_r_values__PartA = module_file["PartA R Values"]
    self.trans_t_values__PartA = module_file["PartA T Values"]
    self.trans_r_values__PartB = module_file["PartB R Values"]
    self.trans_t_values__PartB = module_file["PartB T Values"]
    self.some_thing_loss_total__PartA = None
    self.some_thing_loss_total__PartB = None
    self.esw_on_loss_total = None
    self.esw_off_loss_total = None
    self.esw_loss_total = None
    self.err_loss_total = None
    self.device_loss_total__PartA = None
    self.device_loss_total__PartB = None
    self.module_loss_total = None
    self.delta_tcase_ave = None
    self.delta_value_ave__PartA = None
    self.delta_value_ave__PartB = None
    self.nominal_value_ave__PartA = None
    self.nominal_value_ave__PartB = None
    self.delta_value_max__PartA = None
    self.delta_value_max__PartB = None
    self.nominal_value_max__PartA = None
    self.nominal_value_max__PartB = None
    self.value_max_PartA_list = []
    self.value_max_PartB_list = []
    self.thermal_interp_is_four_degree = self.check__thermal_interp()
    self.switches_per_degree = None
    self.input_output_freq = None
    self.time_division = None
    self.input_t_sink = None
    self.step_size = None
    self.step_range = None
    self.sec_per_cycle_degree = None
    self.duty_p = None
    self.value_PartA_list = None
    self.value_PartB_list = None
    self.time_list = None
    self.rad_list = None
    self.value_max__PartA_thermo = None
    self.value_max__PartB_thermo = None
    self.value_max__time_value = None

def check__some_input_conditions_and_change_input(self):  # todo could this be cleaned?
    blah

def get__max_current(self):
    return max(self.nominal_value_max__PartB, self.nominal_value_max__PartA)

def set__some_module_values(self, is_three_level, system):  # todo call this something different, and break it out for 3-level
    blah

def set_values_for_both_parts(self, input_instance, system_instance, module_location=None):
    lots of blah

def set__current_PartA(self, current):
    self.current__PartA = current

def set__current_partB(self, current):
    blah

def calculate__another_other_loss_for_part_A(self, duty):
    blah

def calculate__another_loss_for_partB(self, duty):
    blah

def calculate__another_loss_for_partA(self, duty=None):
    blah

def calculate__some_loss_for_partA(self, duty=None):
    blah

def calculate__some_loss_for_partB(self, duty=None):
    blah

def calculate__energy_power_for_both_parts(self):
    blah

def calculate__temperatures_for_both_parts(self):
    blah

def calculate__max_temp(self):  # maybe split into PartA and PartB separately?
    self.create_thermal_resistance_dict()
    value_PartA_list = []
    value_PartB_list = []

    next_array_PartA = self.value__PartA
    next_array_PartA = self.rotate(next_array_PartA, -1)
    delta_p_PartA = [next_el - last_el for next_el, last_el in zip(next_array_PartA, self.value__PartA)]
    last_power_PartA = self.value__PartA[-1] - self.device_loss_total__PartA
    first_power_PartA = self.value__PartA[0] - self.device_loss_total__PartA
    value_dict_PartA_added = [self.get_PartA_value_from_time(i * self.sec_per_cycle_degree + self.value_max__time_value) for i in range(self.step_range)]
    value_dict_PartA_added = [old + new for old, new in zip(self.value_max__PartA_thermo, value_dict_PartA_added)]
    value_PartA_inst_init = [self.input_t_sink + self.delta_value_ave__PartA + self.delta_tcase_ave - last_power_PartA * self.value_max__PartA_thermo[i] + first_power_PartA * value_dict_PartA_added[i] for i in range(self.step_range)]

    delta_value_PartB = self.device_loss_total__PartB * self.value_dc__PartB
    next_array_PartB = self.value__PartB
    next_array_PartB = self.rotate(next_array_PartB, -1)
    delta_p_PartB = [next_el - last_el for next_el, last_el in zip(next_array_PartB, self.value__PartB)]
    last_power_PartB = self.value__PartB[-1] - self.device_loss_total__PartB
    first_power_PartB = self.value__PartB[0] - self.device_loss_total__PartB
    value_dict_PartB_added = [self.get_PartB_value_from_time(i * self.sec_per_cycle_degree + self.value_max__time_value) for i in range(self.step_range)]
    value_dict_PartB_added = [old + new for old, new in zip(self.value_max__PartB_thermo, value_dict_PartB_added)]
    value_PartB_inst_init = [self.input_t_sink + delta_value_PartB + self.delta_tcase_ave - last_power_PartB * self.value_max__PartB_thermo[i] + first_power_PartB * value_dict_PartB_added[i] for i in range(self.step_range)]

    for index in range(self.step_range):
        value_dict_PartA_fix = [value_dict_PartA_added[i] if i <= index else self.value_max__PartA_thermo[i] for i in range(self.step_range)]
        # value_dict_PartA_fix_orig = [val for val in value_dict_PartA_fix]
        value_dict_PartA_fix.reverse()

        new_value_PartA = self.rotate(value_dict_PartA_fix, index)
        new_value_PartA = new_value_PartA[:359]
        temp_add_vals_PartA = [delta_p * value for delta_p, value in zip(delta_p_PartA, new_value_PartA)]
        sum_temp_add_vals_PartA = sum(temp_add_vals_PartA)
        value_PartA_list.append(sum_temp_add_vals_PartA)

        value_dict_PartB_fix = [value_dict_PartB_added[i] if i <= index else self.value_max__PartB_thermo[i] for i in range(self.step_range)]
        # value_dict_PartB_fix_orig = [val for val in value_dict_PartB_fix]
        value_dict_PartB_fix.reverse()

        new_value_PartB = self.rotate(value_dict_PartB_fix, index)
        new_value_PartB = new_value_PartB[:359]
        temp_add_vals_PartB = [delta_p * value for delta_p, value in zip(delta_p_PartB, new_value_PartB)]
        sum_temp_add_vals_PartB = sum(temp_add_vals_PartB)
        value_PartB_list.append(sum_temp_add_vals_PartB)

    value_PartA_list = [value + diff for value, diff in zip(value_PartA_inst_init, value_PartA_list)]
    value_ave_PartA = self.nominal_value_ave__PartA - np.average(value_PartA_list)
    self.value_PartA_list = [value + value_ave_PartA for value in value_PartA_list]

    value_PartB_list = [value + diff for value, diff in zip(value_PartB_inst_init, value_PartB_list)]
    value_ave_PartB = self.nominal_value_ave__PartB - np.average(value_PartB_list)
    self.value_PartB_list = [value + value_ave_PartB for value in value_PartB_list]

    self.time_list = [i * self.sec_per_cycle_degree + self.value_max__time_value for i in range(self.step_range)]
    self.rad_list = [i * self.step_size for i in range(self.step_range)]

    self.nominal_value_max__PartA = max(value_PartA_list)
    self.nominal_value_max__PartB = max(value_PartB_list)
    self.delta_value_max__PartA = max(self.value_PartA_list) - self.input_t_sink
    self.delta_value_max__PartB = max(self.value_PartB_list) - self.input_t_sink
    self.value_max_PartA_list = value_PartA_list
    self.value_max_PartB_list = value_PartB_list

def rotate(self, l, n):
    return l[-n:] + l[:-n]

def do_calculation_for_either_part(self, step, spcd, index, scalar, growth, time):  # todo does everything need to be passed in?
    blah

def get_other_part's_value(self, time):  # todo could this be folded into below
    blah

def get_one_part's_value(self, time):
    blah

def integrate_value_for_other_part(self, step, spcd, start_time, index):  # todo could this be folded into below
    blah

def integrate_value_for_one_part(self, step, spcd, start_time, index):  # todo remove interp check
    blah

def create_some_dict_for_both_parts(self):  # todo could this be cleaned
    50 lines of blah

def get__other_corrected_array(self, array):  # todo could this be simplified?
    blah

def get__corrected_array(self, input arrays):  # todo is this necessary
    blah

def get__some_value(self, value):  # todo isn't there one of these already?
    blah

def get__module_name(self, module_file):
    blah
```

Comment: Always good to show code. [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is a helpful guideline. Maybe the smallest representative subset of your class so people can see the problem without a) spending a week reading, and b) so you don't show all your assets? :)

Comment: Yep, I read all the way through, and it was actually explained quite well. But we are coders here... Coders need code if they are going to give you a proper answer

Comment: Sure thing, I will add some as soon as possible here. Give me a sec

Comment: Also your class Module is empty.

Comment: `dict`s, `dict`s, and more `dict`s, if not more classes. For example, `self.trans = {'r': {'A': ..., 'B': ...}, 't': {'A': ..., 'B': ...}}` instead of `trans_r_values__PartA` et al.

Comment: @MarkSteiner instead of having `self.attribute = default value`, I would define a `self.dict = {}` and fill a few of its keys `self.dict[key] = initial value` *if needed*. In general I think you could get away with a well placed `self.dict.get(key, default value)` which has the advantage of putting the default value where you need it in the code, instead of in the `__init__`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The commentators are correct that an MCVE would definitely enhance your post and so my answer is a bit limited. I just want to point out that your data members can be any python object.

So if your data access pattern would benefit from storing your data in pandas and interacting with it as pandas:

```
class YourClass:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = # Your pandas df
```

Or json:

```
import json
class YourClass:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = json.loads(data)
```

Or numpy:

```
class YourClass:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = # Your numpy ndarray
```

And then your class can be called simply as `YourClass(data)`

Edit: Looking at your code, literally ALL of your `self.value = None` lines are superfluous in my view. if they are a members of a tabular data input they can be initialized:

```
class Module:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = pd.DataFrame()
```

Once they are initialized as an empty dataframe their CRUD operations can map to the very mature `pandas` CRUD operations. Similarly `self.data = {}` for key-value pairs data structure like JSON, and so on. For the rest, you can catch the case where `data.key` is undefined in generic getters and setters and not bother with initializing them.

Comment: I added an MCVE (more of a CVE...sorry). I think it explains a little better. My init area is not so much a problem. It is that I need so many variables within that class, but as you can see, many are repeats of the same variable, but just for PartA or PartB, which is always contained by a module. Even the functions are repeats, just for PartA or PartB based on the values needed. Currently I'm using a dict as init input, it works fine. It's the output variables that are killing me. And I am keeping only what I want, leaving unneeded variables in functions. still huge.

Comment: I appended to my answer @MarkSteiner as best I could based on your definitely not minimal CVE

Comment: Okay I understand. That is a good idea, building a dataset programatically instead of leaving them as distinct variables. What do you think about breaking out the functions into other classes? Is there any value to doing that, or better keep it the same?

Comment: I'm actually having trouble seeing the value of even the one class @MarkSteiner. There are already tools for complex data engineering workflows (like Luigi and Airflow) which are going to be more mature than your solutions

Comment: As I mentioned, I am a total noob and this is my first project. I just looked up Luigi and it looks promising.

Comment: If you're new, then you're in the right place @MarkSteiner. If my post addressed your question then you can mark it as answered or helpful.